# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Failed to compile.

```
./src/Components/Hooks/useFirebase.js 26:36
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (26:36)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   var location = useLocation();
|   var history = useNavigate();
>   var redirect_uri = location.state?.form || '/';
|   var FacbookProvaider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
|   var GoogleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```

Comment: which version of react-router you're using ?

Comment: Optional chaining operator: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining